# No Windows Security GUI on Server 2019

Tags: windows-defender, windows-server-2019

I just noticed today that none of my Server 2019 boxes have a Windows Defender GUI or anything down by the clock to even suggest it is running. It is installed and running on all of them but no GUI. If you google it all articles say the GUI in a separate item in Add Roles but when I look it is not a separate role and there is no option for "Windows Defender GUI".

It is like Microsoft started out that way but has changed things and not told anybody. So where is the GUI for Windows Defender on Server 2019?

[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the Add Roles and Features Wizard, Features section, with the branch of "Windows Defender Features" fully expanded.

Comment: Screen shot has been added. It isn't just this 2019 server. It is all of them. There is no GUI option as the documentation suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing features, so most likely you are using the lame
Windows Server 2019 Essentials.

To quote from the article
[Windows Server 2019 Essentials – end of an era!](https://www.theofficemaven.com/news/windows-server-2019-essentials):

> While Microsoft will still be releasing an “Essentials” SKU for Windows Server 2019, it will be completely devoid of everything that we recognize as being part of Windows Server Essentials in its current form.
>
> Basically, Microsoft is releasing their first (and last) non-essentials Windows Server Essentials release that is completely gutted of anything even remotely resembling Windows Server Essentials as we currently know it. And obviously, without the underlying “Essentials” bits, there can be no more new WSE RemoteApp or WSE WorkFolders product releases going forward.
>
> My suggestion to those who want to continue running an on-premises Essentials server would be to grab up as many Windows Server 2016 (Standard, Datacenter, or Essentials) licenses as you possibly can (before they’re all gone), and then ride it out with that particular version for as long as Microsoft will be providing support for it (see: [Windows Server 2016 Essentials servicing timeline](https://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search?alpha=Windows%20Server%202016%20Essentials)).

I advise to skip Windows Server 2019 Essentials and get instead
Windows Server 2016 Essentials, or get a higher version of
Windows Server 2019 that is not Essentials.

Comment: I have 5 2019 Servers. Of those 5, 4 are Standard and only 1 is Essentials. None of the 5 have any options in Add Roles under Windows Defender. All 5 look just like the screenshot above so it isn't just the fact that it is Essentials. As a footnote I am glad to see they got rid of all the frivolous BS in Essentials.

Comment: It seems that I have to rewrite my answer. I have fired up a Server 2019 Standard, and in fact this option is missing. Question: Which GUI are you looking for in addition to the one provided by *Settings > Windows Security*?

Comment: I was looking for the shield down by the clock but here are a few more "oddities". There is a Settings > Update & Security (no Windows Security there) then Windows Security but none of the features open. When you click on any of them all you get is "You'll need a new app to open this Windowsdefender). About the only way to see anything is to Search for Windows Security at which point the app shows up and the sub categories will display but even at that trying to display Manage Providors doesn't yield any. It is as if they have completely abandoned Windows Security in Server 2019.

Comment: For me, Manage Providers shows none because I have none. You get "You'll need a new app" because Server has no UWP apps, and especially the Microsoft Store. On Server, applications must be installed using PowerShell. Many GUI features you're used to on Windows 10 do not exist here and must be done from the PowerShell command-line. It's a different way of working that's not consumer-oriented.

Comment: That kind of goes back to the original question about Windows Defender and Server 2019. Everything you Google says there should be a GUI and a multi-level Roles option. There isn't. Then if you look on a W10 the Security Provider says Microsoft Defender and shows it as being on. What is in the docs doesn't match the real world. Is or is Windows Defender supported on a 2019 server?

Comment: Windows Defender is certainly supported, but GUI seems to have been discarded: Running `Install-WindowsFeature -Name Windows-Defender-GUI` gives error  "InvalidArgument: (Windows-Defender-GUI:String)". My answer should maybe be extended to more Windows Server 2019 SKUs than only Essentials.